# Why "... and thus be called" but not "...and thus to be called"?

Tags: modal-verbs, complementation, bare-infinitives

In the book A Complete Guide to Programming in C++ by Ulla Kirch-Prinz and Peter Prinz, I encounter a sentence:

> Manipulators are functions that can be inserted into the input or output stream and thus be called.

Would anyone please explain me why it is "... and thus be called" but not "...and thus **to** be called"?

Comment: There's no "just" in that sentence at all. ["Thus" is a completely different word](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define+thus&form=OSDSRC).

Comment: Many thanks Nathan. It is exactly the sentence from the book. By the way, would you please comment on what the grammar of "be called" is?

Comment: *Which* is the sentence from the book? You have three different quotes; one of them is the full sentence, with "thus", another is the trailing bit, but with "just", and the last is a hypothetical variant, also with "just". "Thus" is almost certainly the correct word here, and is also the first one used, so you should [edit] your question to make sure you're consistent, and asking about exactly what the book says. At present, at least part of your question is sure to be wrong. (You should also check the definition of "thus" to see if that clarifies things.)

Comment: Do apologize for the mistakes in my question. The question has been corrected.

Comment: It's *be called* for the same reason it's *be inserted* and not "to be inserted".  It's much easier to see if you simplify the sentence:  "Manipulators...can be...called."  You wouldn't say "Manipulators can to be called."

Comment: Good question +1 Welcome to ELL :-)

Answer (score 2):

The auxiliary *can* takes a bare infinitive as a complement, not a *to*-infinitive:

> I **can** **read** a book in one sitting.　 　 *(OK)*
>   *I **can** to **read** a book in one sitting.　*(ungrammatical)*

And you can see that in your example, too.  Both clauses with *be* are complements of *can*, so in both cases we need bare infinitives:

> Manipulators are functions that **can** [**be** inserted into the input or output stream] and [thus **be** called].

In other words, we can't insert *to* because *can* doesn't allow it.

The adverb *thus* is grammatically optional here and adds a meaning similar to 'as a result'.